# Good German novels to help further my German

Tags: german, literature

I'm looking to improve my German by reading a book, translating it as I go. That's pretty much how I learned LaTeX, C, Python, and Bash, so why can't it work with normal languages as well, right?

Are there any good sci-fi/fantasy novels or novella which aren't especially difficult to read that also have English translations (so I can compare my translation)? I tried The German version of *An Artificial Night* by Seanan McGuire, but I think that was a bit above my level. I figure something more in the young adult section would be better.

I took German in college, so I do have a decent enough grasp of the grammar (or so I think). It's more my vocabulary, and familiarity with the conjugations that need work.

Comment: We cannot recommend "good books" because "good" is entirely subjective. Fortunately, there are many web sites that _do_ provide this service. Amazon and Goodreads come to mind. I suggest looking up book reviews on these sites to find books you are likely to enjoy in your target language.

Comment: You can recommend books that you feel are good. As for these services, I've never really found such things to be useful. Personal recommendations have always been what I've found to use helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately, subjective recommendations are strictly off-topic on this web site. We focus on objective questions and answers as much as possible.

Comment: Apparently, you need 20 reps to use the chatroom. Posting a good answer or a good question should help.

Comment: There is a [related question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/620/simple-but-interesting-german-literature?rq=1) on German.SE

Comment: You can try almost anything by Cornelia Funke, her German is close to the spoken variety (not too "bookish") and not particularly difficult. Of course, there are some typical triggers of fantasy language in there. Another recommendation: Tschick by Wolfgang Herrndorf.

Comment: @jknappen I can also remember reading some of the *Kalendergeschichten* and the *Geschichten vom Herrn Keuner* by Bertolt Brecht. And later *Siddhartha* by Hermann Hesse.

Comment: Could you add a more precise description of your level? And replace "good" with that level as a selection criterion? See also [Recent German novels (and other literature) for level B2](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/2830/800).

Comment: @Flimzy:  This query is specifically about bi-lingual German sci-fi and fantasy literature or novellas that can be used as a learning resource, i.e., the name and/or authors of books that have or include [ English? ] translations of the printed text.  Such resources clearly will enable the questioner to cross-check his/her own translation of the German text being read so that any mistakes he/she has made in his/her translation can be corrected.  I have an excellent German grammar book that has a chapter titled "Bi-lingual Reading Exercises" that does that, but I can't answer a frozen query.